# Radiation is Painful

Tags: code-golf, quine, radiation-hardening

A [radiation-hardened quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)#Radiation-hardened) can take a hit and stay standing, but nobody ever said that the quine can't be a *wuss* about it.

For this challenge, you should write a quine that:

- If no characters are removed, prints its source code normally.
- Iff any one character is removed, prints the original program's source code, followed by a new line and then this text:

  ```
  Owie! That hurt!
  ```

  You should **only** print the original plus that.

[Standard quine rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) apply for this challenge, and the shortest valid code in bytes wins. See also [Radiation Detector!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154286/62402)

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds to the site beyond the quine and radiation hardened quine challenges.

Comment: There's a little bit of new complexity in both retaining the same behaviour while irradiated, while also being able to tell that it has been irradiated.

Comment: Can I choose which character is deleted?

Comment: @seshoumara no, you can't. That'd sorta defeat the point of radiation-hardening.