# Output the Missing Character

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, error-correction

When writing a programm 1 missing character can ruin everything,
wouldn't it be great if the programm told you what was missing ?

**Task:**

Create any (non Empty) programm, that takes *no input* and *outputs nothing*.

That when 1 Character is removed from the programm, outputs that Character.

**Input:** None

**Output:**

Output nothing if the programm is unmodified.

Output the removed character if one was removed from the programm.

The output is unspecified if any character is changed or added.

The output is also unspecified if more than 1 characters are removed.

The output can not contain any additional characters.

The output can also be an error message, that again must be only 1 character.

**Example:**

If the programm was the following:

```
abcd
```

These 5 Outputs are required:

```
abcd ->  <NO OUTPUT>
abc  ->  d
abd  ->  c
acd  ->  b
bcd  ->  a
```

**Rules:**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) shortest code in bytes wins!

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

**Explain:**

This challenge is not a duplicate of [Radiation Detector!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154286/radiation-detector).

The original program has to output *nothing*.

It is allowed to read your own source code.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/154286/47066)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of Radiation Detector!, this challenge allows reading your own source and the output cannot be repeated. + The original programm has to output nothing.

Comment: The differences are there, but whether or not they're big enough, and how much they might need to be emphasized, is something best evaluated while the question is closed. (Well, it's better in the sandbox...)

Comment: I just noticed my close-vote is a hammer.. Still, I think allowing to read your own source code and outputting nothing for the original program will make it slightly different, but I personally don't think it's different enough. But if someone disagrees feel free to vote to re-open and give some arguments why the differences are big enough. PS: Don't feel discouraged that your first challenge is a duplicate, it happens pretty often for new users unfortunately. Feel free to post it in [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/52210) to get feedback, and enjoy your stay!

Comment: @peterzuger also, hi, welcome, GREAT first challenge. Most people do not do their first challenge so amazingly well. Please don't be discouraged by how strict we are here; and do use the sandbox, it's a good place to play around, no pun intended. I want to see more questions from you :). You did very well, just accidentally closely mirrored a challenge.